# TYPO3 10 and Solr Extension - Search for partial Title not working

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-10.x, solr8

I am new to the Solr topic.

TYPO3 10.4.26

Solr-Ext 11.2.0

solr-spec 8.11.1

I have the following problem:
There is a file search by title, here it searches for "forklift" as an example. Solr then also finds files whose title contains "forklift" but not "forklifttest". Only if there is the whole word. It would be good if it is possible to search for "fork" and get "forklift" results.
How can I influence this? Maybe someone can help me.

Here you can see my index.queue settings for downloads. (Without additionalWhere because I do not think this will cause the problem)
I also tried _textNgramS = title but it doesn't seem to work

```
        downloads = 1
        downloads {
            indexingPriority = 160
            table = sys_file_metadata
            additionalPageIds = 1,0
            fields {
                title = title 

                tabgroup_stringS = TEXT
                tabgroup_stringS.value = downloads

                size_intS = SOLR_RELATION
                size_intS {
                    localField = file
                    foreignLabelField = size
                }

                fileExtension = SOLR_RELATION
                fileExtension {
                    localField = file
                    foreignLabelField = extension
                }

                title_textS = SOLR_RELATION
                title_textS {
                    localField = file
                    foreignLabelField = name
                }

                url_stringS = SOLR_RELATION
                url_stringS {
                    localField = file
                    foreignLabelField = identifier
                }

                storageUid_intS = SOLR_RELATION
                storageUid_intS {
                    localField = file
                    foreignLabelField = storage.uid
                }

                storage_stringS = SOLR_RELATION
                storage_stringS {
                    localField = file
                    foreignLabelField = storage
                }

                category_stringM = SOLR_RELATION
                category_stringM {
                    localField = categories
                    removeEmptyValues = 1
                    multiValue = 1
                }

                description = description
                keywords = keywords
                author = creator
            }
        }
```

I didn't make any changes to solr schema.xml or other solr stuff and hope i don't have to :D

If you need further informations let me know.

Comment: It's about ngrams and edgeNgrams... In short: you have to configure your field in another type: https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/pull/947

Comment: you need to add those solr-fields to your query (`plugin.tx_solr.search.query.queryFields = ...`) with weights, so they may give results.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) 
edgeNgrams works as desired but I don't know why textNgramS doesn't work for the case.
Thank you! :)